# Как подключиться к веб-сокету?

Tags: javascript, php, websocket

Когда я локально разрабатывал то делал так: `new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080')`, но когда хотел перенести проект на сервер то понял что это так не работает)) Пытаюсь вот так сделать

```
new WebSocket(`ws://${location.host}:8080`)
```

Но не подключается... Сокет остается в состоянии CONNECTING.

P.S. Бэкэнд на PHP и Ratchet.

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь ранее уже был создан вопрос с подобной темой

Answer (score -1):

Подобная структура поможет вам подключится к сокету

```
const HOST = location.origin.replace(/^http/, 'ws');
// OR
const HOST = `ws://${location.host}`
const socket = new WebSocket(HOST);
```

Comment: Зачем origin если есть host? И потом я же сказал что не подключается.

Comment: @ПЭХАПЭШНИК Вы уверены что порт корректный?  Попробуйте убрать порт

Comment: @ПЭХАПЭШНИК https://learn.javascript.ru/websocket Ранее грузил на heroku все работало. Можешь использовать location.host без порта

Comment: Так вообще сразу пишет connection failed

Comment: А на сервере у тебя что?

Comment: В посте же написано. Ratchet

Comment: @ПЭХАПЭШНИК У Вас нет кода сервера, возможно возникла проблема именно там. Строить догадки и тыкать пальцем в облако не очень помогает решить Вашу проблему. Чаще всего  проблема кроется именно в коде. Почему так не работает а так работает не раскрывает ясность в сути проблемы. Мой ответ и правда не корректен. Указал сервер Node JS.

Comment: Весь код не хочется выкладывать, но он на базе этой библиотеки: https://github.com/consik/yii2-websocket (а она уже на базе Ratchet). Там кстати в Ридми пример чата, я сделал по аналогии.

Comment: Слушайте, я кстати почти уверен что у меня просто порт закрыт на сервере... Проблема в том что я не знаю как их открывать(

Comment: хостер тока может открыть, если пожелает, а может и не открыть.

Comment: @Jean-Claude да у меня есть все доступы, включая ssh рутовский. Я просто не знаю что вводить...

Comment: Все, открыл. Заработало)